# Activate a meteor user without sending an activation email

Tags: meteor

I have an application that i have built and i want to create login credentials for users. Since the app is only available on a local network(intra-net) i want the users to skip having to activate their accounts via email.

I created an account with this code

```
Accounts.createUser({email: "hidden@gmail.com",password:"123456"});
```

and this is the account in the

```
db.users.find().pretty()
```

this is the result

```
{
    "_id" : "up6WA7JmPzEQtXznt",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-22T20:46:14.299Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$INrFYYAfQ4nUqQjM8TCmKez2Ni0NPU9s51AOolX4I0sXHZFi5WxkK"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2016-04-22T20:46:14.385Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "w9W2/XZNS8r3zGdo8tIFqf2zPFiRuuMhpQIAIlle8Jk="
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "hidden@gmail.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i verify my email without sending an activation email?.

I found this function http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_verifyemail

to verify the account. How can i obtain the token to start with?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to verify your users at all. [`Meteor.loginWithPassword`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) would work with unverified email addresses just as fine.

Verification flag is more like a hint for you. You could for example disable parts of your app until you're certain that the address really belongs to the user. But in your case it's unnecessary.

Comment: This allows me login with the email and password i have created?.